# Initialize union with array?

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to create a datastructure for network communication (TCP),  where I can build up a byte array from small tagged pieces (like in serialized class). And of course I need a reverse behavior of this, I need a pieces from a byte array that is why a I put a constructor to the union.

```
typedef union message {

    struct {
        int header;
        int payload;
    } pieces;
    int whole[2];

    message (int* arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            whole[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    message ():iVal(){}
} Message ;

main() {
    int a[2] = {10, 2};
    Message msg(a);
}
```

This snippet is working. I'm just curious is there any other or better solution?

Comment: Why not simply use a class Message instead of a union?

Comment: And how do I create a byte array from that? In arduino we have limited resources which why this union solution looks suitable for me.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with arduino, just to mention. My comment was actually about curiosity. Can you give me an example of where it is used as byte array? Also, what if you'd go with having a class store a byte array and make header and payload to be methods that address a certain part of the array?

Comment: Actually that is what I did at the server side (in Java). After I prepared the array a call `client.write(buf, len)` function. I just cant see the advantages or disadvatages of the solutions. And I read somewhere in arduino it is good to stick to the old-fashioned (C) way. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientWrite

Comment: @Aziuth: arduino is an embedded environment, that means you are very restricted regarding program size and available RAM (order of kiB). So, if you can simplify message parsing to `char buffer[SIZE]; recv(buffer, 0, SIZE); Message *msgs = reinterpret_cast<Message*>(buffer);` reusing the same memory, you'd have more resources available than if you first had to copy them. Introducing `Message` as a class might interfere with that method (e.g. if a vtable were to be generated, not only doesn't the memory layout match anymore requiring a copy, you'd also need additional memory for the pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old trick is to cast a pointer to an array of bytes to an pointer of a struct (POD) with the exact memory layout of the final message(s).

```
struct Message {
    int header;
    int payload;
};

// parsing bytes -> messages
char buffer[SIZE];
recv(buffer, 0, SIZE); // replace with actual code for receiving
Message *messages = reinterpret_cast<Message *>(buffer);
size_t max_message_count = SIZE * sizeof(char) / sizeof(Message);


// converting messages -> byte array
Message messages[MSG_COUNT];
// initialize messages
char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<char *>(messages);
size_t byte_count = MSG_COUNT * sizeof(Message) / sizeof(char);
```

However, this requires a strict memory mapping between the message struct and the serialized byte format (so `Message` in this case has to be a POD struct). Yes, this effectively bypasses the type system, but if used properly its the fastest way of parsing messages (and in case of embedded systems the reuse of the memory is a nice touch).